# Why doesn't the Fontawesone-Icon show up?

Tags: html, css, angular, icons, font-awesome

So I'm working on a project for school and want to include fontawesome-icons. My problem is that no icon, no matter which one I use, does show up. I tried it in an empty html-file with just a blank page and in that case it works. Can someone tell me why it doesn't show up in the image below? Thanks in advance!

[Code of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrtGw.png)

```
...    
<head>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/505871b650.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: It would be way better if you included some text code in your question, instead of providing a link to an image :)

Comment: Yes I know, the insert code thingy just appeared to be a bit buggy/unclear. Thanks for the suggestion, tho!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want things to be simple just put the following inside you `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And you don't need to use `<script>` tag to integrate fontawesome, take a look a this [doc](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

Comment: Well, now it works. Thanks for the fast and simple answer, I really appreciate it. (:

Comment: don't forget to accept my answer and upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: Hi, could I ask why a script tag cannot be in a head tag? That seems to be a good place to put them. You can use defer if you don’t want to hold things up on loading. I may be missing some point here. (I realise this is not directly relevant to the solution given here, but for clarity for those landing here later on),

Comment: I mean sure you can put script tags inside a head tag, but in general you want to put them at the end of your document, just because you want to query the document when it is fully loaded. I edited my answer